# Yii using quickdlgs to create new records in CGrid view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, yii-extensions

In my web application I need to  create an iframe button using quickdlgs for creating new records. But when I click the I frame button I am not getting the 'create' web page but I am getting an empty Iframe.
My actionCreate code for the controller

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
    $model=new Store;
        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
        if(isset($_POST['Store']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Store'];
            if($model->save())
            {
              EQuickDlgs::checkDialogJsScript();
             $this->redirect(array('admin'));
             }
             $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
               EQuickDlgs::render('create',array('model'=>$model));
            //  $this->redirect(array('create'));

}
}
```

My view code for the iframe

```
<?php
EQuickDlgs::iframeButton(
    array(
         //'id' =>'create',
        //  'renderOpenButton' => false,
        'controllerRoute' => 'create',
       //'url'   =>'/store/create',
        'dialogTitle' => 'Create Store',
        'dialogWidth' => 500,
        'dialogHeight' => 500,
        'openButtonText' => 'Create new',
        'closeButtonText' => 'Close',
        //'closeOnAction' => true, //important to invoke the close action in the actionCreate
        'refreshGridId' => 'store-grid', //the grid with this id will be refreshed after closing
    )
);
?>
```

This code I have written in the admin.php view page. But when I click the iframe button I am getting an empty iframe instead of the create button. Any body kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `EQuickDlgs::render('create',array('model'=>$model));` should be outside the scope of `if`.

Comment: it worked .I got the output .thks.. But after  I use other buttons like edit or delete and then use create ,i need to refresh the page to  use the create button again. Can you help me how to fix this problem?